# How to open a PDF file synchronously from a batch file

Tags: pdf, batch-file

I want to open a PDF file from a batch file and only continue running that batch file once the user closed the PDF file.

This:

```
start "" /WAIT "test.pdf"
```

waits for the application to close, not the file. so if other files are open, it doesnt work as desired.

How does it work?

Comment: Have you tried `start "Reading PDF" /wait "Path/to/acroread.exe" "test.pdf"`

Comment: i didnt test that because i dont want to have an explicit path to the reading application (since acrobat always puts the version numbers in the path). but i also dont see what difference that should make. i'll try.

Comment: My Experience is, that your Version will wait for the FILE to be freed, while the other version will wait for the APPLICATION to end.

Comment: actually that works, but only with the reader. acrobat pro tells me "The file cannot be found." with the very same line. weird. my default opening program is acrobat pro.
my newest idea is to look for a program like taskkill, only taskwait or something, which can look for windows titles and wait for them to close.

Comment: Just an idea: you could use `ASSOC .pdf` to find the identifier assigned to the `.pdf` file type, then use `FTYPE identifier` to get the name of the executable, and then you would be able to have the executable open the file, using `START /WAIT`.

Comment: @peter, do you want the batch file to stop executing the next line until the PDF reader is closed? I'm not sure about what you want

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you should write

```
start "" /WAIT "test.pdf"
```

if you want that /wait switch to matter (otherwise it's passed to adobe and I don't think it's going to take such orders from you). Of course, this line will wait for the adobe application to finish (and not for the file to be closed) - to detect file closing you'll need some window-title-handling solution, like in autoit:

```
ShellExecute("test.pdf")
WinWait("test.pdf")
WinWaitClose("test.pdf")
```

As for Acrobat Pro not being able to find the file - did you provide the full file path to it? You'd better, it's not always obvious what directory is current for another application.
So you must do

```
start "" /WAIT /D"C:\WhateverFolderShouldBeCurrent" "test.pdf"
```

Comment: yeah, i have the wait in that position in my real file, i was not careful enough when typing the question. 
i found out that it works if no other pdf files are open, but fails if they are. so you are right about the application thing. 
in the past, taskkill could not kill just one adobe window, but now it can, adobe has improved. i was hoping that it was the same here.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `"title"` is not optional if you want `start` to process parameters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use this line in your batch file:

```
test.pdf
```

and be sure that .pdf extension as linked to acroread.exe. For additional details: START /?

Comment: I saw this behavior too:  just specifying the file name was enough to load the associated application and pause the batch file. Didn't test with multiple files open in the same app, though, which I think is what the OP was asking.

Comment: also, he said that some computers didnt have reader they had pro